# correctly close QMetaObject::Connection

Tags: c++, qt

Im not a Qt nor a C++ dev but for a small task I have to register a QMetaObject::Connection.

My question is, how to I correctly close a connection

```
QMetaObject::Connection _sessionStarted = Q_NULLPTR; //or nullptr
```

gives me
`error: conversion from 'std::nullptr_t' to non-scalar type 'QMetaObject::Connection' requested`

I also have to check at some place if I do have a connection by

```
if (_sessionStarted == Q_NULLPTR)
```

which works but how do I reset it?

I also tried `delete _sessionStarted` and checked the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check the connection's (`QMetaObject::Connection`) validity by casting it to `bool`. It's not a pointer, but an object.

Comment: Also remember that the `Connection` will automatically become invalid if one or both of the `QObject`'s involved in it are destroyed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QMetaObject::Connection` as a value type, not a pointer. It is basically like a smart pointer to the internal connection data. To create an "invalid" connection, just create one using the default constructor:

```
QMetaObject::Connection _sessionStarted;
```

Same goes for checking validity:

```
if(_sessionStarted)
    //Connection is valid and active
```

To "delete" a connection, i.e. disconnect the slot from the signal, use the `QObject::disconnect` method:

```
QObject::disconnect(_sessionStarted);
```

Comment: It might be obvious but the `if (_sessionStarted)` works because of the `bool Connection::operator bool() const` operator overloading.

Comment: @Scab was not obvious to me when reading docs, this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject-connection.html#operator-bool appeared quite confusing, glad I found this post

Comment: Also, it's not an `operator bool()` but an `operator RestrictedBool()`, where `RestrictedBool` is a typedef for some bizarre `void*` magic which I have no idea why it exists.